# SQL Server, Returning a summed data set grouped by a single column for a merge query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a data set like the following:

```
BaseID| SecondaryTypeID| Value    
------------------------------
1       5                1
1       5                3
1       5                8
```

What I'd like to get is something like:

```
BaseID| SecondaryTypeID| Value    
------------------------------
1       5                12
```

Now, I can return that data set with the following:

```
select BaseID, 
       SecondaryTypeID, 
       (select sum(Value) from TableA) as SummedValue
from TableA
group by BaseID, SecondaryTypeID
```

However, I can't do that as part of a merge query, the inner select breaks the merge with an error that looks like this:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints
>   defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any hints
>   and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this would be gratefully received!

Comment: Why would you use a subquery to calculate the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you use a subquery?  Just do:

```
select BaseID, SecondaryTypeID, sum(Value) as SummedValue
from TableA
group by BaseID, SecondaryTypeID;
```

If you have multiple rows in the result set and want the overall sum, then use window functions:

```
select BaseID, SecondaryTypeID,
       sum(sum(Value)) over () as SummedValue
from TableA
group by BaseID, SecondaryTypeID;
```

This is what your query *really* is saying to do.  I doubt it is what you want.

Comment: Thank you - I don't know why I hadn't just done it the simple way (I think the "sum" kept saying I needed to have the value in the grouped by information).